# Piping Output asks for parameters

Tags: powershell

In the CLI itself

```
$foo = (Get-ADGroupMembers -identity"blah_SEC")
echo $foo
```

Works.

But when I do the same exact thing in a .ps1 file it says the parameters are missing and prompts me to input them.

Comment: I don't know why you're getting a "missing parameter" error. You should actually be getting a bit worse. Firstly, you'll get a "command not found" type of error - the command is `Get-ADGroupmember`, ***not*** `Get-ADGroupMembers`. After that, you should get a "cannot find an object with identity:" error because there's no space between `-Identity` and `"blah_SEC"`. After you fix that in your script, try putting a semicolon at the end of the first line for good measure and see if it works.